# How change the color text 'today' UIDatepicker - Xcode?

Tags: xcode, colors, uidatepicker

I changed the color of the datepicker (UIDatePicker) with the line `datePicker.setValue(color, forKey: "textColor")`
But the label 'today' is always black !.

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387791/uidatepicker-change-color-of-text-of-today-date