# UIDatePicker Change color of text of "today" date

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I know that this question as been made other times, but with xCode 7 and iOS9.2 is it possible to change the font color of "today" date on a UIDatePicker?

```
[self.dpData setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:111/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:121/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forKeyPath:@"setHighlightsToday"];
```

I tried this and it crashed, so I know that this don't work.

Any other options that I have, or I really need to build my own DatePicker?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more search I found the solution.

```
[_dpData setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:111/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:121/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forKeyPath:@"textColor"];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString( @"setHighlightsToday:" );
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature :
                            [UIDatePicker
                             instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
BOOL no = NO;
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setArgument:&no atIndex:2];
[invocation invokeWithTarget:_dpData];
```

With this solution we can change the color of the text (even today date) without problems.

Comment: If someone looks at this in the future, turns out this approach doesn't work with Swift, since NSInvocation is unavailable.

Comment: Also, set value for highlightsToday crashes in iOS 14.

Answer (score 11):

(It has been reported that this approach crashes in iOS 14 so it is no longer valid. Please see the discussion below.)

A safer/easier way to do it is to simply set the value of the key "highlightsToday". Here's a Swift 2.2 example:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

Comment: Sadly, this makes the current day not shown as "Today" too.

Comment: Set value for highlightsToday crashes in iOS 14.

Comment: @danil you found any solution on ios 14

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas unfortunately, no I didn't

Comment: bro you can update your picker design plz refer to this
https://www.swiftpal.io/articles/new-uidatepicker-in-ios-14

Comment: Hey. It looks like iOS 14 crahes only if datePicker design is set to Automatic or Compact (new date picker design in iOS14). But when I set it to Wheels - it works fine even in iOS 14).

Comment: not working for iOS 16, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I used the same method Richardo until now, but it is using a private api that could always become unavailable or Apple might reject it.
I just changed my code (as hacky and ugly as it is) to just change the date picker to a different mode and back - this causes the Today color to get the textColor that was set before.

```
selectedColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.TimerPicker setValue:selectedColor forKeyPath:@"textColor"];
[self.TimerPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[self.TimerPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
```

good enough for me.

Comment: I was using this for a while, but causes a crash if the DatePicker is being used when the change happens.

Answer (score 1):

Actually given answers are still actual even for iOS 13.4 or 14. The reason of the crash is that you can set these parameters only for date picker with classic (Wheels) style:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

By default date picker has Automatic style:
[image]

So if device has iOS 13.4 or higher installed, it will use [Compact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle/compact?changes=_7) style. But older iOS versions will use Wheels style.

So to solve the issue with iOS 13.4 or higher you should add a condition based on UIDatePickerStyle (it's available starting from 13.4). Like this:

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            let style = self.startDatePicker.datePickerStyle
            if style == .wheels {
                self.startDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "textColor")
                self.startDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
            }
        } else {
            self.startDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "textColor")
            self.startDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
        }
```

Another way is to use classic date picker style - Wheels by setting it's style explicitly in a StoryBoard builder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Going through the documentation for this class and it's parent class it says it's still not possible

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806

Yes you should make your own, since with an item picker it's possible.

This is really stupid on Apple's behalf

Comment: I know that apple doesn't like us to tamper with UIDatePicker, but that doesn't make sense.. btw I found a solution and I'm going to post it as answer now. Thanks nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, however you can force the dark mode on UIDatePicker:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle.dark
}
```